# How to call a method of a specified instance of another class file in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my storyboard, I have two different audio controllers (play, record, stop buttons plus a progress bar) on one ViewController.  I have a separate class that handles all the audio functionality (using AVFoundation framework), and I want to know how get the buttons to correspond to the correct audio file.

I assume I would initiate a new instance of the audio class for each set of buttons, but how do I get, for example, the first play button to call a method from the first instance of the audio player and the second play button to call the same method but from the second instance?

I am also assuming that the buttons are outlets of the ViewController, not the audio class.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. You have two audio players, each having 3 buttons. You have two audio files. Your problem is that you don't know which play button was tapped?

Comment: Im guessing you would want to have a singleton class of your audio controller and you would just want to play/pause/record/stop etc - one audio file at a time right? Just use that across your app and have each ViewController access the instance.

Comment: The buttons have different outlets, so I can tell which button was tapped, but I want the first button to play the audio file created but the first instance of the audio player class, and the second play button to play the audio file created by the second instance, but I don't know how to refer to the different instances

Comment: Have a model class (which would be a singleton) which creates and owns both instances of the audio classes. When the user presses on one set of buttons call a method on the model called something like playAudioOne, and when the user presses on another set of buttons call a method on the model called playAudioTwo.

Comment: JAManfredi - That's correct, I just want to control one audio file created by the singleton class at a time, I'm just not clear on the syntax for hooking up one button to one instance, and the other button to the other instance.

Comment: Woofbeans - that's along the lines of what I was thinking, so how do I make playAudioOne method refer to the first instance, and playAudioTwo refer to the second instance?

Comment: I don't really understand the reason for your latest confusion. If the two audio players are properties of the model then the playAudioOne method would call something like [self.audioPlayerOne playAudio]. I think there's a misunderstanding on your part of something fundamental, or you've architected your app in some way (which maybe isn't standard) and I'm not understanding what it is you are not understanding. Maybe adding more more detail to you question would help to clarify for everybody reading. Post a screenshot of your storyboard and details of your current audio handling class.

Comment: You shouldn't "hook" one button up to an instance. Have a singleton model (as Woofbeans specified) which has a method like playAudioWithIndex:(NSInteger)index where index

Comment: OK, I think it's starting to make sense. I just need the syntax for declaring the instance in the first place. Would it be: self.audioPlayerOne = [[audioPlayer alloc] init]; or would declaring AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayerOne in @interface take care of the instance?

Comment: You need to do both - you need to declare the instance as a property and then alloc it. Take some time out to read some iOS fundamentals, you seem to not know the  basics from chapter one of any iOS book, and a few hours spent reading now will save time later. Don't try to run before you can walk ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I think I've got it figured out.  I think I just over-complicated the problem in my head when trying to work in the audio stuff too.  This is all stuff I've done before, but none of the iOS tutorials I've done do a great job of explaining functionality beyond the dinky little demos they do :-P
Thanks for the help anyways!